# How to iterate json list with dict in python

Tags: python, json, django, list, loops

I am calling data via an API and want to write that data to my Django model.
The API provides me with a JSON with the following structure:

```
"results": [
        {
            "key1": "value",
            "key2": "value"
         },
         {
            "key1": "value",
            "key2": "value",
         },
         {
            "key1": "value",
            "key2": "value",
         },
         ....
```

My code looks like this:

```
    def get_data():
        try:
            response = requests.get(settings.HOST+settings.PATH, verify=False)
            for data in response['results']:
                print(data)
                mydata = MyModel.add(**data)
            return results
```

I get this error:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.5284.44)
{'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value'}
list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Process finished with exit code 0


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 983, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 913, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/user01/Repository/api-test/myapi/myapp/management/commands/getapidata.py", line 27
    get_data()
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
python-BaseException
```

What I am doing wrong?

A screenshot of the variables in PyCharm

[image]

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace, so we can tell what the error is referring to.

Comment: What is the point of including this severely-cropped image?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added the full traceback

Comment: It is `response = requests.get(settings.HOST+settings.PATH, verify=False)`, not `response: requests.get(settings.HOST+settings.PATH, verify=False)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, thats true, but not the issue. I do not use copy paste writing this question... In my code it looks like this response = requests.get(settings.HOST+settings.PATH, verify=False)

Comment: try   response = requests.get(settings.HOST+settings.PATH, verify=False).json()

Comment: @Jisson I tried this allready, but get this: ''''list' object has no attribute 'json''''

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My code worked for the most part. Another dict in the json caused the problem. In the model while processing the JSON I did not add another loop and that was the problem. I comment-in this part and all works fine.

Thank you all for you time!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you don get the json from response.

like @Jisson said.

you need to call `.json()`

```py
    def get_data():
        try:
            response = requests.get(settings.HOST+settings.PATH, verify=False)
            json_response = response.json() # new
            for data in json_response['results']: # modified
                print(data)
                mydata = MyModel.add(**data)
            return results
```

Comment: I tried this allready, but get this: ''''list' object has no attribute 'json''''

Comment: how comes that response is a list ?

Comment: results is a list with dicts